# Can't figure out why my React Component isn't rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is there an issue with how I imported react or am I just missing something small? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty new to programming so there's probably a really simple solution here that I'm just not informed enough to see. Thanks.

Edit:
After taking out the commented out portion of the body, the component still doesn't render. I get this error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at index.html:22:13)

Can the file not understand that I'm trying to use a react component? Thanks.

2nd edit:
Solved it, I was missing type="text/babel" in the script element.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- React Import -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

    <title>Markdown Previewer</title>
  </head>

    <script>
      class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return(
            <div class="">
            Hi
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App/>,
      document.getElementById('app'));
    </script>

  <body>
    <!--<wrapper>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80" id="editor"></textarea>
      <div id="preview"></div>
    </wrapper>-->
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your element with the id `app` is commented. Therefore the JavaScript can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

remove comment braces: `<!-- -->`

and write just:

```
<wrapper>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80" id="editor"></textarea>
  <div id="preview"></div>
</wrapper>
```